# how to preserve regex using stringr (str_split) or strsplit with r

Tags: r, stringr

I have some filthy data that needs tidying.  Here's an example:

```r
x <- "FIRST LAST Sep 1, 2020   1234567 Jan 1, 1985 555-555-5555 100 Main St. Somewhere, CA 90009  Atorvastatin Calcium Cetirizine HCl Diflucan Flonase Allergy Relief Hydrochlorothiazide HydrOXYzine Pamoate Oct 1, 2020 Sep 1, 2020   1234567 Jan 1, 1985 555-555-5555 

FIRSTA LASTA Sep 12, 2020   2234567 Jan 12, 1985 555-555-5552 1002 MAIN AVE, CA 90009 DR. JOHN SMITH Cetirizine HCl Diflucan Flonase Allergy Relief Hydrochlorothiazide HydrOXYzine Pamoate Oct 12, 2020 Sep 12, 2020   2234567 Jan 12, 1985 555-555-5552 Smith REX

FIRSTB LASTB Sep 13, 2020   3234567 Jan 13, 1985 555-555-5553 1003 Main St. Somewhere, CA 90009  Cetirizine HCl Diflucan Flonase Allergy Relief Hydrochlorothiazide HydrOXYzine Pamoate Oct 13, 2020 Sep 13, 2020   3234567 Jan 13, 1985 555-555-5553 Somewhere"
```

I'm trying to get a table with single column and rows of data split by first -space- last name (all caps, e.g. FIRST LAST, FIRSTA LASTA, FIRSTB, LASTB), while preserving said name.  I started with base strsplit but gave up. Here are my stringr attempts:

```
str_split(x, "[A-Z]+ (?=[A-Z]+)")
```

This is pretty close but I loose the names.

```
str_split(x, "(?<=[A-Z]+) (?=[A-Z]+)")
```

This throws an error due to lack of bounded maximum.

Expected output:

```r
[1] FIRST LAST Sep 1, 2020   1234567 Jan 1, 1985 555-555-5555 100 Main St. Somewhere, CA 90009  Atorvastatin Calcium Cetirizine HCl Diflucan Flonase Allergy Relief Hydrochlorothiazide HydrOXYzine Pamoate Oct 1, 2020 Sep 1, 2020   1234567 Jan 1, 1985 555-555-5555 

[2] FIRSTA LASTA Sep 12, 2020   2234567 Jan 12, 1985 555-555-5552 1002 Main St. Somewhere, CA 90009  Cetirizine HCl Diflucan Flonase Allergy Relief Hydrochlorothiazide HydrOXYzine Pamoate Oct 12, 2020 Sep 12, 2020   2234567 Jan 12, 1985 555-555-5552 

[3] FIRSTB LASTB Sep 13, 2020   3234567 Jan 13, 1985 555-555-5553 1003 Main St. Somewhere, CA 90009  Cetirizine HCl Diflucan Flonase Allergy Relief Hydrochlorothiazide HydrOXYzine Pamoate Oct 13, 2020 Sep 13, 2020   3234567 Jan 13, 1985 555-555-5553
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Does `strsplit(x, "(?<=\\d) (?=[A-Z]{3,})", perl=TRUE)` do the trick?

Comment: Yes Onyambu, that worked for the sample I originally posted.  My real data is more complex and does not end with digits consistently. I've adjusted the sample to make more representative of the real data.

Comment: probably you should consider `strsplit(x, "(?<=[^A-Z])\\s+(?=[A-Z]{3,})", perl = TRUE)`

Comment: I see where you are going with the regex. Makes sense. I have some cases of ALL CAPS in the data, so I did update the sample again in case anyone has ideas. otherwise the code works good.

Comment: The question is how do you know the first and last names?? You need to be as specific as possible so that you might not end up splitting at the wrong point

Comment: if at all you have your example as given , then you could as well split on the LF character. ie  `strsplit(x, "\n")`

Comment: @Onyambu that's pretty much it. if he doesn't have a multiline record that'll be the best option.

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you want is to get each record, if so you need to split on either the newline that precedes a first name last name:

```r
str_split(x, "\\n(?=[A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+)")
[[1]]
[1] "FIRST LAST Sep 1, 2020   1234567 Jan 1, 1985 555-555-5555 100 Main St. Somewhere, CA 90009  Atorvastatin Calcium Cetirizine HCl Diflucan Flonase Allergy Relief Hydrochlorothiazide HydrOXYzine Pamoate Oct 1, 2020 Sep 1, 2020   1234567 Jan 1, 1985 555-555-5555 \n"
[2] "FIRSTA LASTA Sep 12, 2020   2234567 Jan 12, 1985 555-555-5552 1002 MAIN AVE, CA 90009 DR. JOHN SMITH Cetirizine HCl Diflucan Flonase Allergy Relief Hydrochlorothiazide HydrOXYzine Pamoate Oct 12, 2020 Sep 12, 2020   2234567 Jan 12, 1985 555-555-5552 Smith REX\n"
[3] "FIRSTB LASTB Sep 13, 2020   3234567 Jan 13, 1985 555-555-5553 1003 Main St. Somewhere, CA 90009  Cetirizine HCl Diflucan Flonase Allergy Relief Hydrochlorothiazide HydrOXYzine Pamoate Oct 13, 2020 Sep 13, 2020   3234567 Jan 13, 1985 555-555-5553 Somewhere"
```

Dynamic length lookbehinds aren't supported by the underlaying regex library that's used by `{stringr}`

Following the discussion with **@Onyambu** if you're dataset doesn't have line feeds i.e newlines you can use the following:

```r
str_split(x, " +(?=[A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+ \\d{2}, \\d{4} +\\d{7})")
[[1]]
[1] "FIRST LAST Sep 1, 2020   1234567 Jan 1, 1985 555-555-5555 100 Main St. Somewhere, CA 90009  Atorvastatin Calcium Cetirizine HCl Diflucan Flonase Allergy Relief Hydrochlorothiazide HydrOXYzine Pamoate Oct 1, 2020 Sep 1, 2020   1234567 Jan 1, 1985 555-555-5555" 
[2] "FIRSTA LASTA Sep 12, 2020   2234567 Jan 12, 1985 555-555-5552 1002 MAIN AVE, CA 90009 DR. JOHN SMITH Cetirizine HCl Diflucan Flonase Allergy Relief Hydrochlorothiazide HydrOXYzine Pamoate Oct 12, 2020 Sep 12, 2020   2234567 Jan 12, 1985 555-555-5552 Smith REX"
[3] "FIRSTB LASTB Sep 13, 2020   3234567 Jan 13, 1985 555-555-5553 1003 Main St. Somewhere, CA 90009  Cetirizine HCl Diflucan Flonase Allergy Relief Hydrochlorothiazide HydrOXYzine Pamoate Oct 13, 2020 Sep 13, 2020   3234567 Jan 13, 1985 555-555-5553 Somewhere"
```

If the name is uppercase as **@Onyambu** suggested then the regex could be simplified :

```r
tr_split(x, " +(?=[A-Z]+ [A-Z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+ \\d)")
[[1]]
[1] "FIRST LAST Sep 1, 2020   1234567 Jan 1, 1985 555-555-5555 100 Main St. Somewhere, CA 90009  Atorvastatin Calcium Cetirizine HCl Diflucan Flonase Allergy Relief Hydrochlorothiazide HydrOXYzine Pamoate Oct 1, 2020 Sep 1, 2020   1234567 Jan 1, 1985 555-555-5555" 
[2] "FIRSTA LASTA Sep 12, 2020   2234567 Jan 12, 1985 555-555-5552 1002 MAIN AVE, CA 90009 DR. JOHN SMITH Cetirizine HCl Diflucan Flonase Allergy Relief Hydrochlorothiazide HydrOXYzine Pamoate Oct 12, 2020 Sep 12, 2020   2234567 Jan 12, 1985 555-555-5552 Smith REX"
[3] "FIRSTB LASTB Sep 13, 2020   3234567 Jan 13, 1985 555-555-5553 1003 Main St. Somewhere, CA 90009  Cetirizine HCl Diflucan Flonase Allergy Relief Hydrochlorothiazide HydrOXYzine Pamoate Oct 13, 2020 Sep 13, 2020   3234567 Jan 13, 1985 555-555-5553 Somewhere"
```

Comment: He did edit this question each and every time we posted a question. You will note that he wanted us to visually see the x. at first, x was just a long string with no line feeds. So technically, i do not think this is what OP had in mind, but i might be wrong

Comment: @Onyambu yeah I knew the markdown wasn't right and I edited it. like you the first thing that popped to my head when I saw the title was use lookarounds, now it seems like an overkill.

Comment: You will note that in the comments, I would post a regex that works then OP would edit the question. Probably the line feed was added later on. But I do not think that OP has the LF in their dataset

Comment: @Onyambu I found a pattern mainly the first name is followed by the last name by a date then a 7 digit number

Comment: That is a great way to approach this

Comment: Probably you should consider the first name and the last names to be upper case

Comment: @Onyambu ok this will simplify the regex. Thanks for the help